# Debugging scriptcs in VS code on Windows

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, scriptcs

Is it possible to debug scriptcs (in a .csx file) in VS Code on Windows ?

[this](https://gist.github.com/glennblock/b1cc0446abae0ba9127b094e9607751c) document describes how to do it on a Mac and using Mono.

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39923990/launch-json-for-debugging-scriptcs-within-vs-code) previous question might be relevant to this but has been removed.

The comments on [this](https://www.strathweb.com/2015/11/running-c-scripts-and-snippets-in-visual-studio-code-with-scriptcs/) page from 2 years ago indicate that it doesn't work.

Any update on whether this can now work on Windows ?

UPDATE: I have installed mono (on Windows) and set up my launch.json as documented in the first link (although I removed the externalConsole parameter as this seems to have been deprecated). This then allows me to debug using the mono debugger, but debugging does not stop at breakpoints - it runs the script to the end, disregarding breakpoints.